# Poorly coded JQuery: naming dependancies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a few tabs on a page that have this markup

```
<div id="holiday-details-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="holidaydetails-description" title="Overview" href="#tab-holidaydetails-overview">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a class="holidaydetails-included" title="Rooms" href="#tab-holidaydetails-rooms">Rooms</a></li>
                    <li><a class="holidaydetails-itinerary" title="Rates" href="#tab-holidaydetails-rates">Rates</a></li>  
                    <li><a class="holidaydetails-accommodation" title="Information" href="#tab-holidaydetails-information">Information</a></li>                         
                    <li><a class="holidaydetails-reviews" title="Reviews" href="#tab-holidaydetails-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The hiding and showing of the content in these tabs are controlled by some JQuery code that begins thus

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Hide all tabs apart from the overview
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-rooms').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-rates').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-information').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-reviews').hide();
    ...
```

The problem is that if I add, remove or rename tabs (like I have just done), then I have to change all this code.  What I would like is to add, rename or remove as many tabs as I like but to not have to modify this JQuery code.

I'm not really looking for someone to code a solution for me but rather wanted to start a discussion on tools, techniques etc that can be used to avoid this sort of naming dependency.

**EDIT**

I also have this bit of ugliness for when a tab is clicked.

```
$('#holiday-details-nav ul li a').click(function () {
    // Remove active class from all links
    $('#holiday-details-nav ul li').removeClass('active');
    //Set clicked link class to active
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    // Set variable currentTab to value of href attribute of clicked link
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    // Hide all tabs
    $('#holidaydetails-description-imagecontainer').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-overview').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-rooms').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-rates').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-information').hide();
    $('#holiday-details-tabs div:#tab-holidaydetails-reviews').hide();

    $('#holiday-details-bottom').show();
    $('#holiday-details-left-booknow').show();

    // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
    $(currentTab).show();

    $('#holidaydetails-description-imagecontainer').show();

    return false;
});
```

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a *common* CSS class, say `tab`, to every `li` *except* overview, and then use a jQuery class selector to hide them all. For example:

```
<div id="holiday-details-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="holidaydetails-description" title="Overview" href="#tab-holidaydetails-overview">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab holidaydetails-included" title="Rooms" href="#tab-holidaydetails-rooms">Rooms</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab holidaydetails-itinerary" title="Rates" href="#tab-holidaydetails-rates">Rates</a></li>  
    <li><a class="tab holidaydetails-accommodation" title="Information" href="#tab-holidaydetails-information">Information</a></li>                         
    <li><a class="tab holidaydetails-reviews" title="Reviews" href="#tab-holidaydetails-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then, to hide every tab except overview:

```
$("holiday-details-nav .tab").hide();
```

Or the other way around, that is, add a specific class to overview, and hide every other tab:

```
<div id="holiday-details-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="overview holidaydetails-description" title="Overview" href="#tab-holidaydetails-overview">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a class="holidaydetails-included" title="Rooms" href="#tab-holidaydetails-rooms">Rooms</a></li>
    <li><a class="holidaydetails-itinerary" title="Rates" href="#tab-holidaydetails-rates">Rates</a></li>  
    <li><a class="holidaydetails-accommodation" title="Information" href="#tab-holidaydetails-information">Information</a></li>                         
    <li><a class="holidaydetails-reviews" title="Reviews" href="#tab-holidaydetails-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, to hide, select all tabs, and exclude overview using `.not()`:

```
$("#holiday-details-nav a").not(".overview").hide();
```

Comment: But then for clicking I have some more ugliness - please see edit above.

Comment: Why not use the title tags for selection as opposed to adding more classes? Title tags are already there.

Comment: Unnecessary to add extra classes, and this still hardcodes stuff, so the OP still has to update the code if they make any changes to the list of tabs...

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with tabs, especially in the setup you have (where the `href` attribute has the id of the div related to it), you don't need to hardcode anything, use the `title` attribute, or use any extra classes. Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/FAM2s/2/

All it does it find all of the tabs' detail divs and hide them all, then only show the one related to what was just clicked.

As long as you set the correct `href` attributes for the links, and set the corresponding divs with those id's, it will work, no matter how many tabs you add/remove whenever you want.